# How to get this array value? (php)

Tags: php, arrays

**Sorry guys i'm actually trying to debug this code [justpaste.it/fh8](http://justpaste.it/fh8) because i cant get it to working. So i suspect it have something to do with the array**

I have this array $compare_colours['red']. When i var_dump it will give this value:

> int(255) int(252) int(255) int(255) int(255) int(164) int(116) int(194) int(255) int(100) int(0) int(0) int(1)

Now how i can manually get the first or second value? So the the first value will be 255 and the 2nd value will be 252.

I try with $compare_colours['red'][0],$compare_colours['red'](http://justpaste.it/fh8) but only get null value.

Thanks.

I get the $compare_colours array from this code

```
$compare_colors = imagecolorsforindex($compare_pic, $compare_rgb);
```

Here is the print_r from $compare_colours

```
Array ( [red] => 255 [green] => 255 [blue] => 255 [alpha] => 127 ) 
Array ( [red] => 252 [green] => 252 [blue] => 252 [alpha] => 126 ) 
Array ( [red] => 255 [green] => 255 [blue] => 255 [alpha] => 127 ) 
Array ( [red] => 255 [green] => 255 [blue] => 255 [alpha] => 127 ) 
Array ( [red] => 255 [green] => 255 [blue] => 255 [alpha] => 127 ) 
Array ( [red] => 164 [green] => 218 [blue] => 148 [alpha] => 44 ) 
Array ( [red] => 116 [green] => 202 [blue] => 115 [alpha] => 21 ) 
Array ( [red] => 194 [green] => 230 [blue] => 182 [alpha] => 64 ) 
Array ( [red] => 255 [green] => 255 [blue] => 255 [alpha] => 127 ) 
Array ( [red] => 100 [green] => 100 [blue] => 100 [alpha] => 50 ) 
Array ( [red] => 0 [green] => 0 [blue] => 0 [alpha] => 0 ) 
Array ( [red] => 0 [green] => 0 [blue] => 0 [alpha] => 0 )
```

When i use var_dump($compare_colors);

```
array(4) { ["red"]=> int(255) ["green"]=> int(255) ["blue"]=> int(255) ["alpha"]=> int(127) }
array(4) { ["red"]=> int(252) ["green"]=> int(252) ["blue"]=> int(252) ["alpha"]=> int(126) } 
array(4) { ["red"]=> int(255) ["green"]=> int(255) ["blue"]=> int(255) ["alpha"]=> int(127) } 
array(4) { ["red"]=> int(255) ["green"]=> int(255) ["blue"]=> int(255) ["alpha"]=> int(127) } 
array(4) { ["red"]=> int(255) ["green"]=> int(255) ["blue"]=> int(255) ["alpha"]=> int(127) } 
array(4) { ["red"]=> int(164) ["green"]=> int(218) ["blue"]=> int(148) ["alpha"]=> int(44) } 
array(4) { ["red"]=> int(116) ["green"]=> int(202) ["blue"]=> int(115) ["alpha"]=> int(21) } 
array(4) { ["red"]=> int(194) ["green"]=> int(230) ["blue"]=> int(182) ["alpha"]=> int(64) } 
array(4) { ["red"]=> int(255) ["green"]=> int(255) ["blue"]=> int(255) ["alpha"]=> int(127) } 
array(4) { ["red"]=> int(100) ["green"]=> int(100) ["blue"]=> int(100) ["alpha"]=> int(50) } 
array(4) { ["red"]=> int(0) ["green"]=> int(0) ["blue"]=> int(0) ["alpha"]=> int(0) } 
array(4) { ["red"]=> int(0) ["green"]=> int(0) ["blue"]=> int(0) ["alpha"]=> int(0) }
```

Comment: Like `$compare_colours['red'][0]`?

Comment: can you please post `print_r($compare_colours);` of your array

Comment: are the `int(x)` values a string you need to parse or an array inside `$compare_colours['red']` ?

Comment: $compare_colours['red'][0] will return null value.

Comment: your array does not have a valid key identifier, did you get that code after `foreach()`?

Comment: i get the array from imagecolorsforindex function

Comment: OK, `imagecolorsforindex` gives you one array with 4 keys. How does that lead to `$compare_colours`? Why do you refuse to dump `$compare_colours` for us? Where you write "here is the print_r from", what follows is *not* the output of a single `print_r`. Stop hiding your real issue and give us your real code and what you really need to do. You're wasting our time and it's not funny.

Comment: even i am confused, this cannot be the real code. are you doing `print_r();` directly after `$compare_colors = imagecolorsforindex($compare_pic, $compare_rgb);` , every array has valid key identifier, and you are missing it.

Comment: Sorry guys i'm actually trying to debug this code http://justpaste.it/fh8 because i cant get it to working.

Answer (score 0):

If $compare_colours is array of colours then you shoud do it the other way around:

```
 echo $compare_colours[0]['red'].' '.$compare_colours[1]['red'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try if you get any output by the following code.

`echo $compare_colours[0]['red'];` OR `echo $compare_colors['red'];`

Answer (score -2):

You could to a foreach loop:

```
$index = 0;
foreach ($compare_colours['red'] as $k => $v) {
  if ($index == 0) {
    $first_value = $v;
  }
  if ($index == 1) {
    $second_value = $v;
    break;
  }
  $index = $index + 1;
}
```

Maybe there is a smarter thing but this is quite fast because you only loop 2 times.